# How to hide sensitive data columns in database

Tags: sql, database, validation, security

Given a table contains name (char) and birthday (date) columns and other columns. These data are privacy related and very sensitive so that we cannot show these values to all of the developing team members. However we still have to be able to test our system on the table.

So I want to hide name and birthday column through one-to-one mapping to update these data. How can I map a name column and birthday column with one-to-one mapping so that the data is still reasonable(especially for date data type).

Or is there any other good idea to deal with this sensitive data related problem?

Further description:

I have development database, which having bogus data, and production database. The problem is that there are too many exceptions in the real data so that we cannot create such a "effective bogus data". The real data is too complicated and so many exceptions so that the system works well on development DB but not on production DB. Due to this problem I want to use real data and hide the sensitive part of that.

Comment: Maybe this is an HR problem rather than a DB one? What if you had your staff sign an NDA or whatever it would be (I'm not a lawyer). Other than that, this link seems very related (https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/obfuscating-your-sql-server-data/)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a development database and a production database? Why not just put bogus data in your dev database and keep your production database locked down?

Comment: I added the further description on my situation.